# Is there a reasonable definition of an octonionic manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, complex-manifolds, fibre-bundles

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\End{End}$

Todorov and Dubois-Violette have recently shown how to understand the structural gauge group of the standard model via octonions.

**Q. Is there a octonionic analog of complex manifolds?**

There is a sensible quaternionic analog. This is a manifold $M$ with almost quaternionic structure and this in turn means that it has a $\GL(n,\mathbb{H}).\mathbb{H}^\times$-structure $H$. Here the dot represents the central product which divides out the direct product by their mutual centre. This is equivalently a subbundle of $\End TM$ with fibre isomorphic as an algebra to $\mathbb{H}$, the quaternionic algebra.

Then a quaternionic manifold is an almost quaternionic manifold that admits a torsion free connection. The bundle $H$ admits a bundle metric and splits into the direct sum of a line bundle $Re H$ and a vector bundle $Im H$. This is akin to the splitting of quaternions into scalar and imaginary parts. Sections of the sphere bundle $S(Im H)$ consists of almost complex structures and then choosing a basis $I,J,K$ we have $I^2 = J^2 = K^2 = IJK = -1$.

Comment: You could consider manifolds of dimension 16 with a Cartan geometry modelled on $(\mathbb{OP}^2,E_6)$, where $E_6$ acts as the automorphisms as a projective plane. I don't know which 16-dimensional manifolds admit these. But then there is the problem of what condition to impose on the torsion, or curvature of the Cartan geometry, to give an analogue of quaternionic manifolds.

Comment: @BenMcKay: In the case of $\mathbb{OP}^2$, which is $E^4_6/P$ in the notation of Kobayashi and Nomizu and where $P\subset E^4_6$ is a parabolic subgroup whose semi-simple piece is $G = P/N = \mathbb{R}^*\cdot\mathrm{Spin}(9,1)\subset\mathrm{GL}(16,\mathbb{R})$, it is known that if a $G$-structure on a $16$-manifold admits a torsion-free connection, then it is projectively flat, i.e., locally equivalent to the $G$-structure on $\mathbb{OP}^2$.  If such a $16$-manifold is simply connected, it admits a devloping map into $\mathbb{OP}^2$ that is unique up to composition with an element of $E^4_6$.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Is the torsion in a vector bundle associated to a $P$-irrep, or could we ask for vanishing of some part of the torsion without breaking the structure group?

Comment: @BenMcKay:  The intrinsic torsion of the $G$-structure takes values in an irreducible representation of $G = P/N$ of dimension 1200, so there's no natural way to separate the intrinsic torsion into 'parts'.  It's essentially all or nothing.  Choosing a $G$-structure on a 16-manifold is choosing a section of a bundle with fiber dimension 210, but setting the intrinsic torsion to zero is 1200 equations on those 210 unknowns.